# Carry out function after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

Seems to be discussed a lot but can't find an easy answer. I want to ensure a function is carried out after I added a loader icon to the DOM but understand append doesn't support this. Are there any easy solutions?

Current code:

```
$('#tab').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    $("#htmlelement").append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
    functionafterappend();
});
```

Comment: In the dupe above, there is an answer that uses `ready()` on the element which calls the append, I would give that a try first

Comment: Stop using synchronous ajax requests.

Comment: @Huangism that's not what .ready() does. in this case it would simply push the request off to run on the next tick, which would be essentially identical to a 0 interval setTimeout. It isn't waiting for anything to be "ready", it just pushes it off to the callback queue because the dom IS ready.

Comment: Yea appears ready is only for doc ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append` is a synchronous function. Therefore, this solution is valid and your `functionafterappend()` will execute only after `append` is executed.

For instance, look at the following example where I'm triggering an alert 3 secs after the append is done

```js
$('div')
    .append(`<p>1. Append at ${console.log(new Date())}</p>`)
$('span')
    .append(`<span> 2. Another Append at ${console.log(new Date())}</span>`);
    
    // setTimeout(() => alert("Append has been completed"), 3000);
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;   
}

div {
  border:2px solid #bbb;
  background-color:#eee;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px auto;
}

span {
  display:block;
  width:65px;
  font:bold 12px Arial,Sans-Serif;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:black;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitr sed diam nonumy tempe goreng.</div>
```

It's the simplest way to do something after an `append`. Except of course, if you wanna chain functions like so:

`.append('<span>1. Append</span>')
.prepend('<span>1. Append</span>')`

If you want to go completely functional, you can even do function composition like so using Lodash:

```
const newFunc = pipe(append, prepend);
```

Comment: Seems like the only one that worked for me. Feels like a hack solution but ok. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing hacky about it. It's the simplest way to do something after an `append`. Except of course, if you wanna chain functions like so:

`.append('<span>1. Append</span>')
.prepend('<span>1. Append</span>')`

And so on. 

If you want to go completely functional, you can even do function composition like so using Lodash: 

const newFunc = pipe(append, prepend);

Adding this to the answer as well

Comment: It is hacky, you are waiting 3 seconds to do something, what if I don't want to wait 3 seconds? What if I want to execute as soon as the appended element is ready?

Comment: Oh I should have clarified. The 3 second wait was not in order to wait for the append to finish. That was in order to clearly show that the functional is called after 3 seconds. You can change it to 0 seconds, or even remove the timeout altogether and it will still function the same. I have updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: In other words, the OP's current code already works lol

Comment: Yup. That's literally what the first two sentences in my answer says :)